# How to embed a Flutter ui view into a React Native app?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, flutter

We are merging some flutter and react native components. Thus, in the React Native app, we need to embed some Flutter views.

Thanks for any ideas and suggestions!

P.S. My naive thoughts: Flutter can be embedded into native Android/iOS apps. At the same time, React Native allow rendering a native component. Thus, I can make Flutter a native Android/iOS component, and then let RN render it. But I do not know whether this will have a huge overhead, or any traps that I have not considered?

Comment: IIRC flutter has a separate rendering engine called skia to render its UI while React Native uses native UI components. I don't think anyone has tried to merge these two. Perhaps you can try it